# Merging multiple tables on key column and different types of columns

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to merge multiple *TSV tables* but I'm struggling to get the outputs I need.

Lets say we have *file1*:

```
K1 V1

K2 V2

K3 V3

K4 V4
```

*file2*:

```
K1 X1 Y1

K2 X2 Y2

K4 X4 Y4
```

*file3*:  (UX is a column we don't want to include in the final merge)

```
K1 UX A1

K2 UX A2

K3 UX A3

K4 UX A4
```

now lets say I want to merge *file1*, *file2* and *file3* all on their keys and selecting certain columns.

So suppose I want a certain output:

```
K1 V1 X1 Y1 A1

K2 V2 X2 Y2 A2

K4 V4 X4 Y4 A4
```

Currently I'm trying to use `join -t$'\t' <(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file1)` etc. ... but I'm facing difficulties because I'm trying to choose certain columns in various different tables.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thank you!

EDIT: So currently I have merged the tables like this:

```
join -t$'\t' <(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file1) \
             <(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file2) \
             <(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file3) > join1.txt
```

...but obviously this does not let me select the columns. I'm trying to use a **awk** loop to try and do it, but it seems more complicated than it should be.

Comment: I showed the statement I have thus far in my edit :)

Comment: just for additional info, I think I can work around the issue by using "cut" to make new files with the specified columns. But again, I think it's a little too clunky.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your attempt with `join` would have worked since `join` accepts only two files at a time.
You can always tell `join` which columns to report. The following works with your data:

```
join -t$'\t' -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.3 \
  <(join -t$'\t' \
      <(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file1) \
      <(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file2) ) \
  <(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file3)
```

Output:

```
K1 V1 X1 Y1 A1
K2 V2 X2 Y2 A2
K4 V4 X4 Y4 A4
```